# Reporting Engine Interface

Tags: reporting-services, interface, user-interface, reporting, report

Two interfaces of Reporting Engine are possible:

1. sql based for sql based user
2. non-sql Based interface for normal non-sql friendly users

Database is very large so how do I go about thinking about 2) option that is Non-sql based interface

How would it be ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or higher, you may want to consider the [ReportBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155933.aspx) supplied as part of [Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/reporting.aspx).

You just need to build a 'business friendly' schema (known as a 'DataSource View') then auto-build a [Report Model](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1115) on top.

The users just connect to the Report Model using the Report Builder tool and they can create their own reports.

If you already have SQL Server, then the additional costs would be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You need an easy way to build SQL queries. Look at the wizards in all the desktop databases, but something that isn't paged might be more intuitive, e.g. http://ruleeditor.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/NSRuleEditor_Tiger.png (not affiliated)